# Dojo 1.8/RequireJS AMD loader and CoffeeScript plugin compatibility

Tags: javascript, dojo, coffeescript, requirejs, js-amd

Both Dojo 1.8 and RequireJS support AMD loader but I have a problem when using  [CoffeeScript plugin](https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs):

- If using Dojo AMD loader: CS plugin is not compatible
- If using RequireJS: dojo/* module are compatible but dijit/* are not (throw errors)

Is there another loader/CoffeeScript plugin for Dojo that is compatible? Or any solution (except using CoffeeScript watch command)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this in the latest Git commit comments?

*3 days ago    update to requirejs 2.1.0*

Comment: I had tried has try the master branch of them on github but they still don't work.

Comment: you need to figure out whats causing the issue.. im thinking, try out dojotoolkit 1.7.3+, requirejs 2.1.0, CS plugin HEAD - and create a form of bug-report to show all info you can accumulate